# iOS Swift Secure Path for user token code

Tags: ios, swift, token

my app is user token base. for every request I want to send token code for server.
I think the best way is after login or register save token on file in secure place and for every request call that token from file.
is this correct way? if yes where is secure place in iOS app? 
if not what is correct way?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a correct way.
And Most secure place for store token/password is KeyChain. it's exactly what Facebook do for storing their session tokens

Refer this it may help you:

https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift

Answer (score 1):

Just save it in the NSUserDefaults

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(deviceToken, forKey: "token")`

And just try to fetch it when needed like this:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("token") != nil { httpParams["token"] = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("token") }
```

Comment: NSUserDefaults is not safe, he must use KeyChain

Comment: Yes,There is no any encryption method in NSUserDefault that why choose KeyChain for secure Data like login auth.